# Error: Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'data'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm trying to creat a UI screen with 3 tabs in it. RecentItem, ReviewItem and Profile. however there's some backend problem in recentitem widget. With the error shown: Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'data'.
Ps: The whole code is quite big hence I have shared a doc for the whole code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qs4ajPJ0DBjserBJ3iBZmPXPz1zTP7tIYSh8vceVQn8/edit?usp=sharing
RecentItems():

```
Widget RecentItems() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .document(uid)
              .collection("recent")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            List orders = List.from(Map.from(snapshot.data.data)['orders']);
            Map order;
            for (int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
              if (orders[i]['orderId'] == widget.map['orderId'] &&
                  orders[i]['homemaker'] == widget.map['homemaker']) {
                order = orders[i];
                break;
              }
            }
            if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                  child:
                  Text("OOPS, Looks like no one is serving!"));
            }
            print(order);
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data.documents[0].data);
              return Container(
                height: 400,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        width: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .width,
                        height: 85,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(child: Text(
                                    "${snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                        .data["dishname"]}", style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                                  //Icon: how to access if food is veg or not
                                ],
                              ),
                              // SizedBox(height:5),
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(child: Text(
                                    "${snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                        .data["homemaker"]}",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),)),
                                  Text("${snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                      .data["rating"]}",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.star, color: Colors.yellow.shade800,
                                    size: 20,)
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              //How to access order date
                              Text(
                                "Ordered ${DateTime
                                    .parse(order['order_placed_at']
                                    .toDate()
                                    .toString())
                                    .day}/${DateTime
                                    .parse(order['order_placed_at']
                                    .toDate()
                                    .toString())
                                    .month}/${DateTime
                                    .parse(order['order_placed_at']
                                    .toDate()
                                    .toString())
                                    .year}}",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            } //
          }),
    );
  }
```

The Error Message is:

```
The getter 'data' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: data
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///C:/Flutter/Naniz_eats/lib/UserProfilePage.dart:434:14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28940): Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'

════════ (3) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'data'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: data
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///C:/Flutter/Naniz_eats/lib/UserProfilePage.dart:434:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things or all might be causing this:

1. the `print` from the first line of `builder`. If `snapshot` was indeed empty you would already be calling data without first checking if it is empty.
2. `snapshot.data.data` which I think is a typo in the second line of `builder`
3. The fact that you are doing operations on snapshot without first checking for `snapshot.hasData`, `snapshot.data.documents.length != 0` to ensure that you are not doing operations on null snapshots.

You should also be able to check specifically which line is causing the error by pressing on the error messages, one of the error messages should contain a link to the specific line (not shown in your question, should be somewhere between the long stacks of error messages)

Comment: the line the error message directs to is 
child: StreamBuilder(

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Firestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .document(uid)
              .collection("recent")
              .snapshots()
```

returns a `Stream` of type `QuerySnapshot`, the problem is here:

```
            List orders = List.from(Map.from(snapshot.data.data)['orders']);
```

the code `snapshot.data` will return an instance of `QuerySnapshot` and `QuerySnapshot` does not contain a instance variable called `data`. So, if you want to a list of documents then you have to do the following:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> orders = snapshot.data.documents;
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query_snapshot.dart#L17

Comment: should i replace the List order line with the solution that you have given

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to achieve, but `documents` will return a List of documents inside the collection so yes replace it

Comment: I'm trying to get data from firebase in a list and will fetch that data to display an UI screen. Well tbh I am just given the code and I just had to built the UI but I cant cause of firebase problems..I've tried to replace but error still persists: error: A value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map'

Comment: is there a solution to it?

Comment: it might be because of this `order = orders[i];` comment the for loop and run it again just to test... you have to debug your code to solve the issues..

Comment: Have u checked it?

Comment: yeah i did the error is back to Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'data'.

Comment: What did u change

Comment: I've comment the for loop as you said